# Terms Aggregation sort by particular field in elastic search 6.5.4 (NEST Client Version 6.X)

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have a query as follows. It is working fine when no sort order is applied. I want to sort them according to the field.

```
var response = await clientProvider.Client.SearchAsync<ProjectModel>(s => s
                                .Index("index_name")
                                .Type("index")
                                .Source(so => so.Excludes(f => f.Field(x => x.FileBase64Data)))
                                .Aggregations(a => a
                                .Terms("by_sort", st => st
                                    .Field(projectName)
                                    .Exclude("x.FileBase64Data")
                                    .Aggregations(ag => ag.TopHits("tops", agt => agt.Size(100).Sort(ss => ss.Ascending(projectName))

                                    .Source(so => so.Excludes(f => f.Field(x => x.FileBase64Data)))))

                                ))

                                .Size(0)

                                .Query(q => q
                                    .Bool(b => b
                                        .Should(

                                            m => m.QueryString(qs => qs
                                                .Query(searchOptions.SearchTerm)
                                                .Fields(ff => ff.Fields(fields))
                                                .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)

                                                ),
                                            m => m.MultiMatch(qs => qs
                                                .Query(searchOptions.SearchTerm)
                                                .Type(Nest.TextQueryType.PhrasePrefix)
                                                .Fields(ff => ff.Fields(fields))
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                     )
                                .Sort(ss => ss.Descending(SortSpecialField.Score))
                                );
```

Now when I am trying sort it using Order as `st.Order(o => o.Ascending("tops"))`. It is popping an invalid response. 
Can anyone help me out with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the invalid response? Can you edit the question and add that detail, please? Where does the `st` in `st.Order(o => o.Ascending("tops"))` come from? If you have a reduced example that can be run that demonstrates what you're seeing, that would be extremely helpful

Comment: @RussCam. I will give an example of what I want to achieve. There are documents named class1,class2....class10.In this class1 I have the list of teachers and students under each teacher for the subject they teach. I need an aggregation based on teacher name i.e TeacherA -> {class1:{{"name":"student1"},{"name":"student2"}},class8:{{"name":"student8"},{"name":"student9"}}}. The above query also returns the same. Please consider this as example and help me out.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to add this further detail. If you have C# POCOs for these, add those too. Take a look at https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ for some guidance on details that might be help with a question.